# Does jQuery have any "find or fail loudly" methods?

Tags: jquery

Consider the following jQuery code:

```
$('.child').closest('.parent').find('.sibling').hide();
```

At every step, if nothing is found, jQuery will fail silently (for example, if there is no `.parent`).

Sometimes that makes sense, but often it just means the code does nothing and you have to troubleshoot why. I'd like the option to do something like:

```
$('.child').closest!('.parent')...
```

Meaning "fail loudly if you don't find this". (Bonus if this could be enabled only when developing.)

Is there anything like that in jQuery?

Comment: I wish... I don't *think* jQuery has anything like that. I'd love to be wrong tho

Comment: @DenysSéguret just hadn't had time to try it. Also, I usually wait a while to accept an answer so that others can vote or give alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's none, but you could make it easily:

```
Object.keys($.fn).forEach(function(k){
  var f = $.fn[k];
  if (typeof f !=='function') return;
  $.fn['_'+k] = function(){
    var o = f.apply(this, arguments);
    if (o && 'length' in o && !o.length) throw "LOUD";
    return o;
  }
})

$("body")._find("unexisting"); // throws LOUD
```

Alternatively, you could replace the existing functions when in debug mode:

```
if (DEBUG_MODE) {
    // let's be more cautious with an explicit list this time
    ['find','closest]'].forEach(function(k){
      var f = $.fn[k]; 
      $.fn[k] = function(){
        var o = f.apply(this, arguments);
        if (o && 'length' in o && !o.length) {
          throw "LOUD"; // you shall make it a more interesting error
        }  
        return o;
      };
    });
}
```

Possibilities are endless as the jQuery prototype is exposed.

Now...The fact jQuery doesn't fail on empty collections is most often useful. Of course you can decide to integrate this code just for a debug/dev session.

Comment: Bravo! This works nicely, and also shows a couple of tricks I didn't know. I found Object.keys() [in the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). Would you mind explaining `if (o && 'length' in o && !o.length)`?

Comment: This checks that `o` (the returned value) exists, that it has a property called `length` ([using in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)) and that this length isn't falsy. I could have simply used `if (o && o.length>0)` but `in` is a little more explicit.